# Trying to fetch multiple api in javascript with promise.all and forEach

Tags: javascript

```
async function someFunction() {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      trendingsSlide.forEach((val) => {
        axios(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${val}?api_key=${api}`
        );
      }),
    ]).then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
someFunction();
```

Why The response is undefined, I tried a lot to fix the problem but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Because `forEach` returns undefined. You wanted `map`, and also to return the promise from `axios` from the callback (which you can do implicitly with a concise arrow function rather than one with a `{}` body):

```
async function someFunction() {
  try {
    await Promise.all(
      trendingsSlide.map((val) => 
        axios(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${val}?api_key=${api}`
        )
      )
    ).then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
someFunction();
```

You could make it a bit more readable (to me, anyway) by using an `async` function with `map`:

```
async function someFunction() {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      trendingsSlide.map(async (val) => {
        const val = await axios(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${val}?api_key=${api}`
        );
        console.log(val);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
someFunction();
```

Comment: But Why He Return Fullfilled in the console?

Comment: Also, no array literal around the `map()`

Comment: @Bergi - Gah! I read right past that in the OP's code.

Comment: @mohahmed123 - Because if you pass a non-promise into `Promise.all`, it treats it as a promise fulfilled with that value. You were effectively doing `Promise.all([undefined]).then(...)` which will call your fulfillment handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have used async/await to wait for your response as you're not doing anything after the response was returned.

Promise.all is enough in your case and no need for unnecessary code blocks

```
function someFunction() {
    const promises = [];
    trendingsSlide.forEach((val) => {
      promises.push(axios(
         `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${val}?api_key=${api}`
      ));
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    }).catch(console.error);
}

someFunction();
```

Hope this might help.